# What is the purpose of the "Message" field when sending a Bitcoin Core transaction?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I always set the "Label", but what is the "Message" for? I always leave the "Message" empty.

I know that neither is sent over the network; they are just for your own reference. But why *both* "label" *and* "message"?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is entirely up to you how to use these fields.

As you noted, the Label and Message are not part of the Bitcoin network protocol, not part of the Bitcoin transaction data or blockchain. But they *can* be communicated to the other party.

The `label` and the `message` are encoded into the QR code that you can generate. So the recipient of the money (sender of goods or services) will see the label and message if they scan a QR code.

The QR code contains text:

```
bitcoin:address?amount=1.234&label=labeltext&message=messagetext
```

So, for example, your label could be "order 12345" and the message could be "For delivery between 9 a.m. and 5 p.m."